# How can I make a site automatically fit device width, without needing to zoom out?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a responsive website that I think looks best when it's 500px or larger, so I set the min-width to 500px.

However, I'm testing it on a 320px phone and pages have horizontal scroll, forcing me to zoom out if I want everything on the screen.

Is this a device issue? Or is there some code I can use to make my site shrink by default? (instead of having to zoom out each time I navigate to a new page)

Comment: Try using Media Queries and breakpoints. http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.6">
```

Then just adjust scale to fit what you need

Answer (score 0):

I used bootstrap in my pages, it save you this hassle, try it it is very helpful in many ways.

[from here.](http://getbootstrap.com/)

and also has many other futures.

[this is a google search for free wordpress templates.](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+wordpress+bootstrap+template)